# Is it possible to update a windows installation located in another drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-update

I have two installation of windows in two different drives. Lately, second drive got corrupted such that it fails to boot to Windows. I am still able to use the first installation to access files on the second.

I prefer to use the drive that corrupted recently. How can I proceed?

Is there any way to directly **update / replace windows on another drive** without disturbing my Settings / Apps / Personal Data ?

Comment: Try the usual way : upgrading via win usb

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://techscsi.com/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd/